# Writing lines from a file

Tags: python

In this sample, I find a string in a file and write the matching line to another file. That is basic and what I can do at the moment.

```
fd_w = open('tt', 'w')
with open('r.0', 'r') as IRR:
    for line in IRR:
        if 'status: ASSIGNED PA' in line:
            towrite = "%s" % (line)
fd_w.write(towrite)   
fd_w.close()
```

What I really want to do is, when there is a matching line, to get the lines prior to the matching line until there is a space and similarly get the lines after the matching line until there is a space.

This is a sample from the file that is being read.

```
admin-c:        DUMY-RIPE
tech-c:         DUMY-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         AS6667-MNT

admin-c:        DUMY-RIPE
tech-c:         DUMY-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         DATANET-NOC
```

I have been trying to sort out how to define two functions, like get previous lines and next lines after matching line. So any idea, any help is highly appropriated.

Comment: Please fix the code indentation.

Comment: To be clear, you want to read everything in one of those blocks if the status is `ASSIGNED PA` and write that to a file. Otherwise discard the entire block?

Comment: that is right; if there is a matching block with ASSIGNED PA keep it, and otherwise simply discard the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the data in blocks delineated by empty lines and test for your status afterwards:

```
with open('r.0', 'r') as IRR, open('tt', 'w') as fd_w:
    lines = []
    for line in IRR:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            # empty line, found a complete block, test for status line
            if 'status:         ASSIGNED PA' in lines:
                for line in lines:
                    fd_w.write(line + '\n')
            lines = []
```

Comment: Instead of line.strip() and then writing line+'\n', you may remove line.strip() and write only line. Will work on all platforms. strip will remove '\r\n' also.

Comment: @shantanoo: The files are opened in text mode, local newline conventions are honoured automatically. I stripped the lines to make testing the matching line easier.

Comment: Thanks @martijn-pieters. Wasn't aware regarding the local newline conventions being honored. IMO, its better not to change the newline conventions. Program output should not be dependent on OS on which it is being run.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a buffer and keep a variable to tell if there was a match in that buffer or not.

Start the buffer when you start reading the file, using a list, for instance.

Append everything to that list, until you get another space, if you find a match in the meantime, use a variable to keep track of that fact.

When you finally get to another space, if the variable is true, use that buffer to do whatever you want, i.e., write to another file.

Reset the buffer, start again.

Do this until the end of the file.